# Why does this PowerPC instruction sequence appear to be setting both cr0 and cr1?

Tags: assembly, powerpc

Upon executing the following set of PowerPC instructions on a big-endian POWER7, why is register r6 == 0b10001000000000000000000000000000?

Is there an implicit condition test from `cmpd`?

```
li r3, 420
li r4, 360
cmpd r3, r4
mfocrf r6, 0x80
```

Comment: As far as I understand `mfocrf` should only ever copy 4 bits so since your set bits are 5 apart, I assume the second one is leftover from previous value of `r6`. The manual isn't clear about whether the other bits are zeroed, so maybe try zeroing `r6` beforehand.

Comment: The version I found says one bit can be set in the instruction but that controls copying of 4 bits. No matter if 1 or 4, that means the rest of the bits are undefined so the second set bit in the question is just random garbage then.

Comment: Zeroing ```r6``` made no difference. Weirder still ```cmpd 7, 3, 4``` results in r6 == 0b10001000.

Comment: How about using `mfcr r6` then?

Comment: I could use ```mfcr``` sure, but I thought it was cheaper to use ```mfocrf``` on newer POWER & PPC processors.

Comment: If `mfocrf` is not giving you any bits except the first 1 or 4, then it's pointless to talk about the other set bit because that's not indicative of the condition register. You should test with `mfcr` which gives you all the bits so you can see what is actually happening with `cmpd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have read closer.

From Power ISA V2.07B:

> The POWER4, POWER5, POWER7 and POWER8
> processors set to 0's all bytes of register RT other
> than the byte that contains the specified CR field. In
> the byte that contains the CR field, **bits other than
> those containing the CR field may or may not be
> set to 0s.**

So this behaviour is expected on the machine I am using.